# mysql - How to combine multiple tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have tbl_room:

```
| room_no | room_type |
---------- -----------
| 101     | Lab       |
| 102     | General   |
```

tbl_teacher:

```
|  t_id   | t_lname |
---------- ----------
|  001    | Asd     |
|  002    | Qwe     |
|  003    | Ghu     |
```

tbl_subject

```
|  code   |  desc   |
---------- ----------
|  M101   |  Fund   |
```

What I want is to combine a column from those tables in one query.

It should look like this:

```
| room_no | t_id | code |
---------- ------ -------
| 101     | 001  | M101 |
| 102     | 002  |      |
|         | 003  |      |
```

Comment: Yes it is.. Give it a try and see how you get on

Comment: I've tried this but its not what I needed 'SELECT t1.room_no, t2.t_id FROM tbl_room t1, tbl_teacher t2;'

Comment: Do you have the code sample of what you have tried so far so we can see that you've actually put some effort into figuring this out yourself?

Comment: There are a number of ways: select from both table, make a join or union between them, etc. Your question is too broad, do some research.

Comment: Tried union but it is returning the result into 1 column only**.

Comment: You're on the right path; most people refer to this as "joining" tables, not combining them.  It seems trivial but Google "sql join tables" instead of "sql combine tables" and I think you'll find some helpful info.

Comment: Note however that there aren't any common attributes to do a join here :S

Answer (score 0):

You should better set `room_no` columns in all 3 tables and then join :

```
SELECT t1.room_no, t2.t_id, t3.`code`
FROM tbl_room t1
LEFT JOIN  FROM tbl_teacher t2
ON t1.room_no = t2.room_no
LEFT JOIN FROM tbl_subject t3
ON t1.room_no = t3.room_no
```

But just for fun here is a query that brings you expected result with data sample provided:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03890a/6

```
SELECT t1.room_no, t2.t_id, t3.`code`
FROM (
  SELECT *, @idx1:=IFNULL(@idx1,0)+1 as idx
  FROM tbl_room
) t1
RIGHT JOIN (
  SELECT *, @idx2:=IFNULL(@idx2,0)+1 as idx
  FROM tbl_teacher
) t2
ON t1.idx = t2.idx
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT *, @idx3:=IFNULL(@idx3,0)+1 as idx
  FROM tbl_subject
) t3
ON t3.idx = t2.idx
```

But it works only in case when we know that `tbl_teacher` holds maximum records between all 3 tables and I set `RIGHT JOIN` for `tbl_teacher`. But this query and your goal described in OP both have no sense. You should link tables between each other by some columns with some relations: one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to many.